# Google Map blue color in Google Chrome 18 Beta

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I'm using google map for my application. When I drag my custom map, Blue and black boxes appear at some places instead of default tiles (gray tiles that are shown when images are not loaded) and they disappear when the map is loaded.

I'm testing on google chrome 18 beta. Here's a screenshot
[image]

The effect only apears when dragging and disappears after the map is loaded

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing similar behaviour with the version of Chrome I upgraded to today: 18.0.1025.142 This is in a page rendered using the iScroll 4 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not test in beta versions.if all the latest stable versions work than you are ok.It's their job to take care of these kind of problems.